# Создание инсталятора в Wix

Tags: c#, wix

Необходимо создать такой инсталятор с помощью набора инструментов WiX, чтобы при установки программы на компьютер запускалась заранее написанная программа, которая записывала бы ключи в реестр.
Такая программа уже написана, но вот возможно ли запихнуть ее в установщик и сделать так, чтобы она активировалась именно при первой установке программы на компьютер?

Comment: А писать ключи реестра в самом установщике не хотите?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

да, возможно, необходимо следующие строчки добавить в конфиг:
строка, указывающая инстолятору, что нам необходима галочка на запуск приложения после установки

```
<Property Id="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOXTEXT" Value="Запустить приложение после окончания установки" />
```

Далее создаем свое действие:

```
<Property Id="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[#appName.exe]" />
<CustomAction Id="LaunchApplication" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixShellExec" Impersonate="yes" />
```

и добавляем тригер:

```
<Publish Dialog="ExitDialog"
    Control="Finish" 
    Event="DoAction" 
    Value="LaunchApplication">WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX = 1 and NOT Installed</Publish>
```

более подробное описание и полный конфигурационный файл можно поглядеть в официальной документации на [оф сайте](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/ui_and_localization/run_program_after_install.html)